# what is a different approach to bind a function to a component React es6

Tags: reactjs

I've got a component like in the example

```
class ItemBox extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.someFn = this.someFn.bind(this);
  }

  someFn(){
    console.log(this)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div onClick={this.someFn}>bla<div/>
    )
  }
};
```

And i wanted to ask - is there some kind of a different solution for binding function to a component, except like i'm using in a constructor ( read it from documentation ). Because i could have 100 functions that i going to pass to child components or using in this component and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this...

```
class ItemBox extends Component {

  someFn = ()=>{
    console.log(this)
  }
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div onClick={this.someFn}>bla<div/>
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    _handleClick = () => {
         console.log(this)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this._handleClick}>bla</div>
        )
    } 
}
```